# Упростить код условия

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Есть код, который в зависимости от значения или заставляет мигать иконку, или скрывает её. Помогите упростить и более правильнее и лаконичнее переписать его

```java
if (_belt_left) {
    if (belt_left.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        belt_left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        belt_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
} else {
    if (belt_left.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE || belt_left.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        belt_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие значения могут быть у энумератора `View`?

Comment: Видно, не видно и скрыто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если всего три состояния, то

```
belt_left.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE || belt_left.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE
```

равнозначно

```
belt_left.getVisibility() != View.GONE
```

Comment: Ну да, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вариант более ёмкий

```java
if (_belt_left) {
    belt_left.setVisibility(belt_left.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    if (belt_left.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE || belt_left.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        belt_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Строк меньше, а читается хуже

Comment: А читать-то особо не надо. Он записан один раз и выполняет работу, а больше ничего и не требуется

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал так

```java
if (_belt_left) {
    if (belt_left.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        belt_left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        belt_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
} else {
    belt_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

void setVisibility(View view) {
  if (view != this.view) {
    ........
  }
}
```